# Creating Surrogate Keys in Access

Tags: ms-access, surrogate-key

I have a project that I am working on where we have to create a registration system for a university in Access. One of the tables requires a surrogate key for one of the fields, and I am not sure how I can create a surrogate key.

The column instructions look like this:

`Field Name     Data Type     Field Size     Caption     Format     Req'd     Index     Unique Key     Ref. Table     Other`

`FacultyID     Text     4     blank     blank     Yes     Yes     Primary     blank     Input Mask '0000;1;_'`

`FirstName     Text     32     blank     blank     Yes     No     Surrogate*     blank     blank`

So the first field, `FacultyID` is straightforward and simple to make. But the `FirstName` field requires a surrogate key that I do not know how to make.

It also has the asterisk next to it, and at the bottom of the page the asterisk reads:

`*Index [LastName], [FirstName]: Duplicates Allowed (surrogate key)`

The `LastName` field is listed later but I didn't show it in my question. What confuses me with this, however, is that in the column instructions, it says that the `Index` field should be `No` for `FirstName`, but this note at the bottom of the page makes it seem like it should be `Yes (Duplicates OK)` and I do not know what to put.

So can anyone help me figure out how to make the `FirstName` a Surrogate Key, and also what I should be putting in the `Index` field?

Comment: Is this a class assignment? What 'page' are you referencing? Is FacultyID an autonumber field? Is this the primary key field? This is the surrogate key. Google the topic. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5431/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key-differences-and-when-to-use-in-sql-server/. Since multiple people can have same names, must allow duplicates in the name fields.

Comment: @June7 Yes this is a class assignment. Sorry, the page I am referring to is a page of instructions the professor provided. `FacultyID` is the primary key but the data type is `Short Text`. It should probably be a `Number` Type but the teacher specified that it should be `Text`

Comment: Then you need to get clarification from instructor because I certainly can't explain that. Did you read the link?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to post more info (like, is there an employees table?), but it looks like the instructions want you to use an employee's last and first name's as a composite key vs. surrogate.  When designing a table, you can hold SHIFT + the fields you want to include in your key:

[image]

Then press the Primary Key button in the Tools section at the top:

[image]

And you'll end up with a composite primary key:

[image]

I think the wording on your requirements sheet is a little wonky.  I think the only way to get a LastName, FirstName column is via some sort of Data Macro or through an append query.

Also, even if you don't use it for anything, I would suggest ALWAYS having an AutoNumber ID field.  I've had database integrity issues when not having a key on each table.

But, without seeing the full assignment sheet, I would be tough to dial-in what you needed specifically.